# Word/phrase that means "the sound that is produced when objects are being moved by a stream"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there a word/phrase for that?

Example:

> I closed my eyes, and listened to the [...] stones.

Comment: What kind of stream has rocks that float?

Comment: _Babbling_ is often used with the word _brook_ and its synonyms to refer to the sound of rapid water flow over and through small obstacles like rocks.

Comment: @JohnLawler - He said the rocks are moving, not water through rocks.

Comment: We're not bound by what he wrote; he's not a native speaker. This is the closest thing to what was asked for.

Comment: @JohnLawler - probably true.  I thought this one might be a stumper.  What is wrong with *rolling*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the size of the stones and other characteristics of the stream and stones, it could be clashing, rattling, grinding, whispering, tumbling (not exactly a sound, but still), grumbling, grating.

Answer (score 1):

Consider *gurgling*

- To flow in a broken irregular current with a bubbling sound.

Answer (score 0):

*Vibrate*

> • [ no obj. ] (of a sound) resonate; continue to be heard

Noun: Vibration.

Answer (score 0):

[*Burble*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/burble) seems like a good choice.

- (*Verb*) Make a continuous murmuring noise:

> "*a stream burbled through the woods*"

- (*Noun*) Continuous murmuring noise:

> "*the steady burble of running water*"

Also *[Babbling](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/babble?q=babbling)*

- **2** (usually as adjective babbling) (Of a stream) make the continuous murmuring sound of water flowing over stones:

> *"a gently babbling brook"*

Answer (score 0):

To my ear, the term that works best in your example is "clatter."

> I closed my eyes, and listened to the [clattering stones](http://www.carlaking.com/dispatches/chinaroad/china14.html).

For denser rocks, consider "[rumble](http://www.dbsaintothelight.org/IssueTwo/IssueTwoPoetryM.html)."